# Send AT command and read serial while 'OK' isn't in the response

Tags: python, pyserial, at-command

I cannot find an answer for this anywhere so I come to you hoping someone can help me with this.

I have a Python script which send AT commands to a ZigBee module via a serial connection and then reads the answer provided by the module. Actually I already can catch and read this answer but sometimes I have undesired characters ending it or no response at all. My goal is to have a perfect output containing the answer and only it.

[Here is an example of this behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mnQY.png)

So, to avoid this I try to read the module response character by character until it contains 'OK' or another expected message returned by the command indicating it's end but the problem is that my code is looping indefinitely since then.

The method I use :

```
def sendAtCommand(command):

# vars
response = ''

if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
    ser.flushInput()
    #flush output buffer, aborting current output
    #ser.flushOutput()

ser.write(command.encode('ascii')+'\r')
#response = ser.read(size=1024)

# while True:
    # response = ser.read(size=1024)
    # if 'OK' in response:
        # break

while True:
    response += ser.read(size=1)
    print(response)

    if 'OK' in response:
        break

print('--------------')
print('Msg received : ')
print('--------------')
print(response)
print('--------------')
```

Comment: It would be better if you could paste your console output as text, directly into a text block in your question, rather than showing a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry but pasting this ouput here makes it very awful at formatting (bold stuffs and odd text size) and I don't have the time right now to understand how formatting works on stackoverflow. But the bright thing is that I've maybe found a solution myself : some AT commands need more timeout to respond properly. I will post an update if it solve this issue.